# Parsing non-csv text file into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing

I have a text file where all columns are merged into a single column and 'rows' are separated by two long rows of '-'. It looks like this:

```
Hash: some_hash_id
Author: some_author
Message: Message about the update


Reviewers: jimbo

Reviewed By: jimbo

Test Plan: Auto-generated

@bypass-lint
Commit Date: 2019-06-30 20:12:38
Modified path: path/to/my/file.php
Modified path: some/other/path/to/my/file.php
Modified path: path/to/other/file.php
-------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------
Hash: some_other_hash_id
Author: different_author
Message: Auto generated message



Reviewers: broseph

Reviewed By: broseph

Test Plan: Auto-generated by Sam

@bypass-lint
Commit Date: 2019-06-30 18:09:12
Modified path: my/super/file.php
Modified path: totally/awesome/file.php
Modified path: file/path.json
-------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------
Hash: hash_id_4
Author: new_author
Message: Auto DB big update



Reviewers: foo

Reviewed By: foo

Test Plan: Auto-generated by Tom

@bypass-lint
Commit Date: 2019-06-30 11:08:59
Modified path: big/scripts/file.json
```

expected output for this example is is a dataframe with just 3 rows.
dataframe columns: Hash (str), Author (str), Message (str), Reviewers (str), Reviewed By (str), Test Plan (str), Commit Date (timestamp), Modified path (array(str))

Comment: post your code/logic

Comment: Hints: Split by lines, then use `key: value` structure (unless the index is always the same, in that case you can skip that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the whole file content into a variable named *txt*.

Then, to generate a DataFrame, it is enough to run a **single**
(although quite complex) instruction:

```
pd.DataFrame([ collections.OrderedDict(
    { m.group('key').strip(): re.sub(r'\n', ' ', m.group('val').strip())
        for m in re.finditer(
            r'^(?P<key>[^:\n]+):\s*(?P<val>.+?(?:\n[^:\n]+)*)$', chunk, re.M)})
    for chunk in re.split(r'(?:\n\-+)+\n', txt) ])
```

Start reading of the code from the last line.
It splits *txt* into chunks, on a sequence of lines containing only `-` chars.

Then `finditer` takes over, dividing each chunk into *key* and *value*
capturing groups.

The next step is a dictionary comprehension, stripping / substituting each
*key* and *value* and creating an *OrderedDict* (import *collections*).

All these dictionaries are enclosed in a list comprehension.

And the last step is to create a DataFrame.

To avoid multi-line items, in each value (the piece of text after the colon)
newlines were replaced with a space (you are free to change it).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one implementation. Loop through each line and when the line contains `:` split the line as `columnname:columnval` and add columnname as key and columnval as value to a temp dictionary. use if statements to detect when you encountered special keys `Hash` (for the start of new row), `Modified path` (add it to an array) and `Commit Date` (converting it to datetime)

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

test_path = '/home/kkawabat/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/scratches/test.txt'
with open(test_path, 'r') as ofile:
    lines = ofile.readlines()
row_list = []
cur_row_dict = {}
for line in lines:
    line_split = line.split(':', 1)
    if len(line_split) == 2:
        colname, colval = line_split[0].strip(), line_split[1].strip()
        if colname == 'Hash': #assuming Hash is always the first element
            if len(cur_row_dict) != 0:
                row_list.append(cur_row_dict)
                cur_row_dict = {}
        elif colname == 'Commit Date':
            cur_row_dict[colname] = datetime.strptime(colval, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        elif colname == 'Modified path':
            if colname not in cur_row_dict:
                cur_row_dict[colname] = [colval]
            else:
                cur_row_dict[colname].append(colval)
        else:
            cur_row_dict[colname] = colval
row_list.append(cur_row_dict)

df = pd.DataFrame(row_list)
print(df)
```